# Gluon - how to create webview to communicate with native (iOS)

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile

The mobile app interface implemented via Gluon must be written in JavaFX, this is not our option, as we need to use HTML/JavaScript/CSS/Reactjs to build the interface.

So I am trying to create an webview (either UIWebView or WKWebView for iOS) in Gluon, so I can load the offline HTML asset, and then I am trying to use the method as described here (https://medium.com/@sreeharikv112/communication-from-webview-to-native-ios-android-app-6d842cefe02d) to communicate between webview and native code (Java by Gluon).

But I can't find any guide to do so in Gluon API, is that possible? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after some time, I have figured out how to achieve this.

Previously I was in wrong direction, checking through all Gluon Charm-down/Attach service to look for the WebView wrapper but couldn't find.

Then I realise the WebView implementation was provided in [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) Port, which mean we can use JavaFX in normal way (like how we do in JavaFX desktop), so we can setup the bridge as per usual and communicate between javascript and Java.

Internally, it is using iOS UIWebView for the implementation, it is not the rework of the JavaFX WebView.